# Errors in installation after upgrading from 11.10 to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, kernel

I've recently upgraded my Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04 . Whenever I'm trying to install some new package using apt-get I'm getting the following error messages in terminal :

```
$ apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get -y dist-upgrade && reboot
```

and this is what I got:

```
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg                                                       
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise Release.gpg                                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                                          
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release                                    
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise Release                                                                  
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                                                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                                                           
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                                                             
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                                                       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources                               
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release                                               
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner i386 Packages                                                    
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg [198 B]                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Sources                         
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                                                                
Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release.gpg [198 B]                                         
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner TranslationIndex                                                
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Sources                                                 
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                                    
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release                                           
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Sources                                                                     
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                                                       
Get:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release [49.6 kB]                       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages                                                         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages                                                   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US                                                                            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages                                            
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                                    
Get:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release [49.6 kB]                      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages                             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex                                                
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                                       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex                 
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Sources                                 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources                                   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex                   
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en_US    
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Sources           
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en   
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en       
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_US           
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages           
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en              
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex                                                                   
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex                                                                   
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex                                                                     
Get:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources [410 kB]                                                               
Get:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Sources [5,467 B]                                                        
Get:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources [93.5 kB]                                                          
Get:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Sources [6,582 B]                                                        
Get:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages [683 kB]                                                         
Get:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages [10.0 kB]                                                 
Get:11 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages [214 kB]                                                    
Get:12 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [13.8 kB]                                                 
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex                                                                 
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex                                                           
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex                                                           
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex                                                             
Get:13 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Sources [2,935 B]                                                           
Get:14 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Sources [14 B]                                                        
Get:15 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Sources [34.9 kB]                                                       
Get:16 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Sources [5,311 B]                                                     
Get:17 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main i386 Packages [2,390 B]                                                     
Get:18 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted i386 Packages [14 B]                                                  
Get:19 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe i386 Packages [35.9 kB]                                                 
Get:20 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse i386 Packages [5,178 B]                                               
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main TranslationIndex                                                               
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse TranslationIndex                                                         
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted TranslationIndex                                                         
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe TranslationIndex                                                           
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                                                                           
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en                                                                     
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en                                                                     
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en                                                                       
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en                                                                   
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en                                                             
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en                                                             
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en                                                               
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Translation-en                                                                 
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en                                                           
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Translation-en                                                           
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en                                                             
Fetched 1,623 kB in 21s (77.2 kB/s)                                                                                                    
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-3.0.0-29-generic linux-image-3.0.0-30-generic linux-image-3.0.0-31-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
13 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 350 MB disk space will be freed.
(Reading database ... 265234 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-3.0.0-29-generic ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.0.0-29-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-29-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-29-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.0.0-29-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-29-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 27: /etc/default/grub: want: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.0.0-29-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.0.0-29-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-3.0.0-30-generic ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.0.0-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-30-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-30-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.0.0-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-30-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 27: /etc/default/grub: want: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.0.0-30-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.0.0-30-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-3.0.0-31-generic ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.0.0-31-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-31-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-31-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.0.0-31-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-31-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 27: /etc/default/grub: want: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.0.0-31-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.0.0-31-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.0.0-29-generic
 linux-image-3.0.0-30-generic
 linux-image-3.0.0-31-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Please someone help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Type in terminal:
uname -r (that will show you the version of the kernel in use)
Case your version is greater than 3.0.0-31 you can remove the versions listed up there. Try to remove them:
sudo apt-get remove --purge  linux-image-3.0.0-29-generic linux-image-3.0.0-30-generic linux-image-3.0.0-31-generic

Comment: My kernel is 3.0.0-32-generic . After running the above command , again I'm getting errors like "Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.0.0-31-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.0.0-31-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.0.0-29-generic
 linux-image-3.0.0-30-generic
 linux-image-3.0.0-31-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
"

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I resolved this issue with removing the postrm files. In your case:

```
sudo rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.0.0-31-generic.postrm    
sudo rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.0.0-30-generic.postrm    
sudo rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.0.0-29-generic.postrm
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt-get -f purge linux-image-3.0.0-31-generic
```

and finally:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
```